# Haro identification

Tags: identify-this-bike, serial-number

Cant find it anywhere the serial number is TIL0C0088. Can anyone tell me what kind of Haro it is?
Thanks

And are there more numbers and letter then just one line of them thos other one has 3 lines of numbers and letters

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  You might be able to get a better answer if you included pictures of your bike; in general serial numbers are notoriously not useful.

Answer (score 2):

In the information on Haro serial numbers posted by Haro enthusiasts I could find no serial number pattern that matched the serial number in the original post.

There is no authoritative way to use a Haro serial number to look up the model of your bicycle.

There are people who have gathered serial number information in order to find clues about the manufacturers serial number methodology.
There are several challenges to this process. Here are a few of them:

1. Getting enough data to be useful
2. There are no standards for serial numbers. A manufacturer can use any number they want and change how it works any time they want to.
3. A brand of bike can be manufactured by different companies (sometimes in different countries) each one with a different system resulting in more than one system for a single brand.

All that being said here is some information gathered by people on the Internet.

From harowiki.com "[Haro Serial Numbers](http://www.harowiki.com/serial-number/)"

> The Haro Serial number page will help you decode, or try to figure out the model of your Haro bike. The serial numbers change from the 90s, 2000, and so on. This will attempt to help you understand the 2000s serial numbers a bit better. Each serial number is made up of nine digits. Within those nine, the first four, or five, contains a model abbreviation, year, and month.

From bmxmuseum.com forums ["Haro Serial Number Info"](https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=206889)

> 2000+ Serial Numbers:
>
> Serial number will contain a model abbreviation and year/month within the first 5 or so digits.
> Year codes interchange month/year, year/month with no blatantly discernable pattern.
> As an example you could possibly have 2 of the same exact bikes, weâ€™ll use an 03 Function 3 (F3) for example
> One serial could read  -   F3W3
> While the other could read  -  F33W
> No difference, same year same model just an oddity seen in the later serials

Later in the post

> 2005+ Serial numbers
>
> Have now seen another difference, but I cannot find the post it was in!!
> Instead of the date code directly following the model abbreviation Iam fairly sure the date code was another 2 digits past where it should beat If I find the info again, this will be updated.

From bmx-catalogue.com the [Haro catalogues from 1986 to 2003](https://bmx-catalogue.com/haro/year.html) where you may be able to identify your frame from the pictures.